# I have a table which has the below data

Tags: sql

The table is

```
Id      name      department        salary
1       ABC       sales             20000
2       DEF       market            30000
3       POL       sales             35000      
4       SWE       market            26000
5       DTR       advert            10000
6       AWK       advert            10000
```

If I add the salary of sales department or market department or advert department and if that each individual department sum is greater than 50000 then that should be displayed in the output ,like if I add the salary is sales department which is 20000+35000=55000 which is greater than 50000 that rows should be displayed in the output is that possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first thing you need to do is work out what RDBMS you are using; you've tagged 3 here (SQL Server, MySQL And Oracle). These are all very different products; find out what you're using and edit your post to tag that RDBMS and only that RDBMS. Next, can you show your expected output please? Your description doesn't make much sense I'm afraid. Finally, please do show us your attempt(s). Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, it's for asking coding questions, after you've tried to solve the problem yourself. If you haven't tried, you should start there. Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `HAVING`.

Comment: try learning SQL first. What you need for this scenario are `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `sum()` aggregate function. This is quite a basic SQL stuff. And there are several tutorials online.

Comment: @raihanul ,I have tried by using GROUP BY,HAVING and SUM() but the output I didn't get the desired one ,thanks for your advice, I know SQL

Comment: @Sanapa Karthik please write your sql query that you already tried here in the comments. Though it's best to edit the question to include your trials.

Comment: ;with cte as (Select dept,sum(salary) as total from table_name group by dept) select * from cte where total>50000

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution (with table creation included).

---

```
-- Create table and add data.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#_data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #_data
CREATE TABLE #_data (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] NCHAR(5),
    [department] NVARCHAR(25),
    [salary] FLOAT
)
INSERT INTO #_data ([name], [department], [salary])
VALUES ('ABC', 'sales', 20000),('DEF', 'market', 30000),('POL', 'sales', 35000),('SWE', 'market', 26000),('DTR', 'advert', 10000),('AWK', 'advert', 10000)



/***
    We'll use a subquery to get the total salary from each department then add in a WHERE clause
    to return only those records above our minimum salary threshold.
    If no minimu salary is given, the default is zero.
*/

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Example with minimum salary value
DECLARE @_min_salary NVARCHAR(10) = 50000

/***
    We first check to see if a value is given
*/
IF @_min_salary IS NULL
    /***
        If no value is given, then we set the minimum salary to zero and get results.
        NOTE: You can also abort the query or have it print a message indicating that
        a salary is required beofre running the query.
    */
    BEGIN
        /***
            Set a new minimum salary value
        */
        SET @_min_salary = 0
    END

/***
    Use a subquery to get total salaries by department.
    Reformat results for a currency format of your choice.
*/
SELECT X.[DEPARTMENT]
,   '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), FORMAT(X.TOT_DEPT_SALARY, '#,#.00')) AS [SALARY]
FROM (
    SELECT department AS [DEPARTMENT]
    , SUM(salary) AS [TOT_DEPT_SALARY]

    FROM #_data
    GROUP BY department
) AS X
WHERE X.[TOT_DEPT_SALARY] > @_min_salary
GROUP BY X.DEPARTMENT, X.TOT_DEPT_SALARY
```

Then your output should be:

```
DEPARTMENT  SALARY
market  $56,000.00
sales   $55,000.00
```